# How to get a slider to Work On CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, image, codeigniter, slider

i am working on a project based on codeigniter. i have tried to add some image sliders to the project but all to nothing.
it only display white screen and nothing else i think its from the codeigniter it self or the server. have any noticed this or have a solution?

i have used the nivo slider its the same i also used jsImgslider and WowSlider all giving me the same result,
I have copy the entire slider directory to my site folder, e.g site.com/themes/default/slider, but still not displaying. 
thanks in Advance

Comment: Please show more image and code

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter does not allow **direct access** to images stored in any subfolder at   **"/application"**. Which path of your images? Try put them in subfolder in main location (like: **example.com/assets**).

Otherwise, check your file **.htacess** has some rule denying access to the folder where you store your images.